# Navbar bootstrap ficando por trás do banner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou colocando o `navbar` do Bootstrap em um site, só que quando clico no botão para abrir o menu, o menu aparece atrás do banner que tem no site. Tirei o `position:absolute` que tem no `col-md-12` e ele ficou em cima (da forma correta), mas queria saber se tem outra alternativa, pois acho que tirar o `position` não é a maneira mais certa a se fazer.

**Print:**
[image]

**Meu código**

```
<div class="row-fluid bg-top">

  <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" border="0">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">

   <div class="navbar-header navbar-default navbar-inverse">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    </div>

 <nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
  <div id="menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">a empresa</a></li>
      <li><a href="">máquinas</a></li>
      <li><a href="">insumos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">cápsulas</a></li>
      <li><a href="">soluções</a></li>
      <li><a href="">contato</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs hidden-sm">

  <div id="contatos">
      <p>atendimento@makecoffee.com.br</p>
      <p>11 2356-6566 | 11 2356-6568 <img src="https://bmwkids.s3.amazonaws.com/app/uploads/2015/02/OrangePhone.png" style="width:8%"></p>

      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
      </div>

</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Alisson Acioli. Utilize o critério z-index no css. Voce deve usar um "z-index" superior para a propriedade de cima e um inferior para a propriedade de baixo. Desta forma, o elemento que está com o maior "z-index" se sobrepõe ao elemento de menor, como se fosse as layers do photoshop.                     Exemplo: <div id="menu" style="z-index: 2;"><div> <div id="header" style="z-index: 1;"></div> .... sacou?

Answer (score 1):

O seu código tem alguns problemas:

- Sua navbar não aparece, ela não está declarada corretamente ou você esqueceu de por no código, ou tá faltando: `<div class"navbar navbar-inverse">`.
- Retire as classes `navbar-default` e `navbar-inverse` da sua `div.navbar-header`, essas classes são utilizadas pela navbar e não pelo navbar-brand.
- Você pode fazer uso das classes [`navbar-static-top`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-static-top) e [`navbar-fixed-top`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) pra auxiliar no posicionamento superior da mesma.
- Você não precisa usar classes responsivas dentro de uma navbar, o bootstrap já faz isso sozinho.

Mais informações você encontra na [documentação da navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), no site do Bootstrap.

Veja abaixo um código de uma navbar que funciona:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
             Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
             Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alisson, você deve usar o elemento **z-index** do CSS para controlar as camadas. Se você puder postar seu código no codepen.io e compartilhar para vermos como foi feito, será mais fácil te ajudar.